# How to set_callback with the "on: :create" option in Rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails model with a `after_commit` callback:

```
after_commit :initiate_post_processing, on: :create
```

In my test I sometimes need to disable this with a `skip_callback` to create an instance. But I need to reactivate this as well with a `set_callback`. The question, however, is: how do I correctly add the `on: :create` option when calling `set_callback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way should be:

`set_callback :commit, :after, :initiate_post_processing, on: :create`

As per https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit (view source to see how after_commit method is constructed)

Comment: To easy. Duh! Thanks, Tom! :)